# Goal Clause as resolvent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have studied the Robinson Resolution Principle and i've notice that my prof considers the goal clauses (used for example in SLD Resolution) as resolvent.
How is it possibile to convert a resolvent into a goal clause ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SLD-Resolution](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA211) uses [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause), written:

> $A \leftarrow B_1, \ldots, B_n$

that are equivalent to "usual" clauses: $\lnot B_1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot B_n \lor A$ [$A$ is called the *head* of the clause]

A *goal clause* is a Horn clause with no positive literals $\leftarrow B_1, \ldots, B_n$ (i.e. $\lnot B_1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot B_n$).

A *program clause* is a Horn clause with one positive literal and one or more
negative literals.

SLD-Resolution consider a set $P$ of program clauses and a goal clause $G$.

A *derivation* by SLD-resolution is a sequence of resolution steps between goal clauses and the program clauses.

The first goal clause $G_0$ is $G$. $G_{i+1}$ is derived from $G_i$ selecting a literal $A_i^j \in G_i$, choosing a clause $C_i \in P$ such that the head of $C_i$ (call it $B_i^0$) unifies with $A_i^j$ by the *most general unifier* $θ_i$ and resolving.

That is, in "usual" clause form, we have:

> $G_i := \lnot A_i^1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot A_i^j \lor \lnot A_i^{j+1} \lor \ldots \lnot A_i^{n_i}$,

and:

> $C_i := \lnot B_i^1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot B_i^{k_i} \lor B_i^0$.

Considering $[A_i^j]θ_i=[B_i^0]θ_i$, we get the resolvent:

> > $G_{i+1} := [\lnot A_i^1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot A_i^{j-1} \lor \lnot B_i^1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot B_i^{k_i}\lor \lnot A_i^{j+1} \lor \ldots \lnot A_i^{n_i}]θ_i.$

As you can see, the *resolvent* $G_{i+1}$ is a new *goal clause*: it has no positive literals.

Comment: So, every goal clause belong to an Herbrand base ? Was it decided this way? That is, the fact that the goal must derive from the horn clauses?