# Correct Answer SLD in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Im studying the SLD derivation for First Order Logic and a question came to me. I've tried to consult many books but i didnt find anything about.

Every time that i produce a SLD Derivation, using the same **mgu** $\theta$ i can produce a **correct answer**. It this true ?

Comment: Please, unwind the acronyms; **mgu** must be *most general unifier*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We [have that](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA210):

> Let $P$ be a program [i.e. a set of *program clauses*] and $G$ a goal clause [e.g. $\lnot A_1 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot A_n$]. A substitution $θ$ for the
>   variables in $G$ is a *correct answer* substitution if $P \vDash \forall x_i[¬G]θ$, where the universal quantification is taken over all the free variables $x_i$ in $[¬G]θ$.

As said in the [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654131/goal-clause-as-resolvent), the new goal clause produced with resolution and unification is the *resolvent* of the previous goal clause and one of the clauses in $P$.

Thus, the procedure of [SLD-refutation](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA212) (like that for propositional resolution) is aimed at the derivation of the *empty clause*, meaning that the set $P \cup \{ \lnot G \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

This amounts to saying that $G$ is *logical consequence* of $P$, i.e. $P \vDash \forall x_i[¬G]θ$ means:

> $P \vDash ∀x_i[(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_n)]θ$.