# First order logic - SLD algorithm

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

When we apply SLD algorithm we start with a definite program P and a goal clause.
Must the goal clause initially be a single atom ? And why ?

Comment: Already answered in the post: [goal-clause-as-resolvent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654131/goal-clause-as-resolvent).

Comment: Thanks Mauro. The thing i dont understand is that , in many definitions ( for example the one for "Close World Assumptions" and "Negation as Failure")  there is a specific reference to atomic goal

Comment: Maybe it's due to the fact the we use one atom at the time , in the sld resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

The [SLD-refutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution#cite_note-2) algorithm is based on the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule), with specific symbolism: it uses [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause), and specific [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution#SLD_resolution_strategies) for computational efficiency.

The "basic form" of resolution rule is simply *modus ponens*:

> $\dfrac { p \to q \quad p } { q }$

written in the equivalent form:

> $\dfrac { \lnot p \lor q \quad p } { q }.$

We may immediatley generalize it to:

> $\dfrac { \lnot p \lor q \quad p \lor r } { q \lor r }$

and then generalize it again to [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) with a finite number of literals.