# SLD Resolution and Logic Consequence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a program P and i start the SLD Resolution with a certain goal clause.
Is **every** clause generated a logical consequence of P ? And why ?

ps: the very fact, is that i havent understood why , starting with a goal clase, we are sure that if a goal clause generate a success **so** this goal clause belong to the Least Herbrand Set....

psS : if every goal is also a logical consequence of P, why if we have a success we are sure that the goal that produce it belong to the Least Herbrand Set ?

Comment: Thanks Mauro, i think i have understood "everthing :) " apart this : "why if we have a success we are sure that composing the mgu we find a ground atom ? Are possibile cases where either the Program P and the goal clauses dont have constant in them and so where i cant get a refutation only using variables?

Comment: Sorry... where does come from: " "why if we have a success we are sure that composing the mgu we find a ground atom" ?

Comment: Very detailded: John Lloyd, [Foundations of logic programming](https://books.google.it/books?id=TeKpCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2nd ed 1993).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) in general, it is a *valid* rule of inference, where the [validity](https://www.iep.utm.edu/val-snd/) property means that:

> it is impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion nevertheless to be false.

Thus, if the *conclusion* of the rule is true wherever the *premises* are, this means that the conclusion is [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of the premises.

---

Regarding SLD, we have that:

> Let $P$ be a *definite program* and $G$ a *definite goal* $\leftarrow A_1, \ldots, A_k$. An *answer* for $P \cup \{ G \}$ is a substitution for variables of $G$.
>
> If $\theta$ is an answer for $P \cup \{ G \}$, we say that $\theta$ is a *correct answer* for $P \cup \{ G \}$ if $\forall x_i[(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_k)]\theta$ is a *logical consequence* of $P$.

This amounts to saying that $\theta$ is a correct answer iff $P \cup \{ \lnot \forall x_i[(A_1 \land \ldots \land A_k)]\theta \}$ ia *unsatisfiable*.

For the definition of SLD-derivation, see the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654131/goal-clause-as-resolvent).

An SLD-refutation of $P \cup \{ G \}$ is a finite SLD-derivation of 
$P \cup \{ G \}$ which has the *empty clause* $\square$ as the last goal in the derivation. If $G_n = \square$, we say the refutation has *length* $n$.

A *computed answer* $\theta$ for $P \cup \{ G \}$ is the substitution obtained by restricting the composition $\theta_1\ldots \theta_n$ to the variables of $G$, where $\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_n$ is the sequence of $\text{mgu}$'s used in an SLD-refutation of $P \cup \{ G \}$.

SLD-refutation is *sound*:

> let $P$ be a definite program and $G$ a definite goal. Then every computed answer for $P \cup \{ G \}$ is a correct answer for $P \cup \{ G \}$.

---

Regarding substitution and unification, we have that a *substitution* $\theta$ is an operation that replaces variables $x_i$ into an expression with *terms* $ti$.

If the $t_i$ are all *ground* terms (i.e. "closed"), the subst is called *ground 
substitution*.

Let $S = \{ A_1,\ldots, A_n \}$ be a finite set of *atoms*. A *unifier* $\theta$ is a substitution such that: $A_1 \theta = \ldots =A_n \theta$.

A *most general unifier* ($\text{mgu}$) for $S$ is a unifier $\mu$ such that any unifier $\theta$ of $S$ can be expressed as: $\theta = μλ$ for some substitution $λ$.

We can prove that:

> Let $P$ be a definite program and $G$ a definite goal $\leftarrow A_1, \ldots, A_k$. Suppose $\theta$ is an answer for $P \cup \{ G \}$ such that $[A_1 \land \ldots \land A_k)]\theta$ is ground.
>
> Then the following are equivalent:
>
> > (a) $\theta$ is correct;
> >
> > (b) $[A_1 \land \ldots \land A_k)]\theta$ is true in every Herbrand model of $P$;
> >
> > (c) $[A_1 \land \ldots \land A_k)]\theta$ is true wit the least Herbrand model of $P$.